# Plural page numbers in inline citations

Tags: bibliographies, pandoc, markdown

My page number term gets randomly pluralized, i.e. sometimes when there is only one page reference, but not always. Using markdown and pandoc, I get:

[image: First reference has pages as "p.31", and second reference gets them as "pp.42": pluralized, even when there is only one page]

from the references `[@Meyer1993, p.31]` and `[@Kalatzi2018, p.42]`, respectively. I was trying to fix it through the `csl` file and managed to change **how** the `p.` or `pp.` get rendered, but cannot find out how to fix **when** the plural is triggered.

This is my full `.md` file:

```
# Minimal example

This is to test why some page-number references appear as plural when they are not. 

This one renders singular: [@Meyer1993, p.31]

This one renders plural: [@Kalatzi2018, p.42]

## Bibliography
```

The pandoc command:

```
pandoc -s --bibliography=references.bib --csl=revista-filologia.csl -N --pdf-engine=xelatex -o example.pdf example.md
```

The bibtex file:

```
@book{Meyer1993,
  address = {{Barcelona}},
  title = {Periodismo de Precisi{\'o}n},
  publisher = {{Bosch}},
  author = {Meyer, Philip},
  year = {1993}
}
@article{Kalatzi2018,
  title = {The {{Principles}}, {{Features}} and {{Techniques}} of {{Data Journalism}}},
  volume = {6},
  language = {en},
  number = {2},
  journal = {Studies in Media and Communication},
  author = {Kalatzi, Olga and Bratsas, Charalampos and Veglis, Andreas},
  month = dec,
  year = {2018},
  pages = {36-44}
}
```

And the `csl` file is "Revista de Filología Española", from the Zotero Style Repository [2](https://www.zotero.org/styles/revista-de-filologia-espanola).

Any clues as to what may be happening here?

Edit: to provide complete minimal example.

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal, reproducible example? Otherwise we have to guess which csl file you are using etc.

Comment: Sure. Edited, I think it's all in there. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue. It seems to be a bug in the CSL file. When formatting the page reference in the citation it makes use of `page` variable instead of the `locator` variable. The following diff seems to fix the issue:

```
@@ -147,7 +147,7 @@
           <text macro="year-date"/>
         </group>
         <group>
-          <text term="page" form="short" suffix=" "/>
+          <label variable="locator" form="short" suffix=" "/>
           <text variable="locator"/>
         </group>
       </group>
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks so much!